# python csv каждый символ добавляется через запятую

Tags: python, csv

Записываю список в csv. Исходные списки: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В результате получается вот такое:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так? и почему только 1 список добавляется в файл?

```
def add_line_in_csv(line):
   with open(file_output, "w", newline="") as file:
      writer = csv.writer(file)
      writer.writerows(line)

for file in list_file:
  my_file=open(file,"r")
  if file==list_file[0]:
    for i, line in enumerate(my_file):
        if i==23:
            text=line[:-2]
            text = ' '.join(text.split())
            text=text.split(" ")
            print(text)
            add_line_in_csv(text)
  for i, line in enumerate(my_file):
    if i > 23:
        text = ' '.join(line.split())
        text=text.split(" ")
        print(text)
        add_line_in_csv(text)
```

Answer (score 2):

Да, надо обернуть в список, так:

```
def add_line_in_csv(line):
   with open(file_output, "w", newline="") as file:
      writer = csv.writer(file)
      writer.writerows([line])
```

Answer (score 1):

Вместо `writer.writerows(line)` используйте `writer.writerow(line)`, тогда каждый символ не будет через запятую

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена, нужно было просто создать список списков

Comment: Лучше в ответе код этого и приведите